# Add characters on multiple lines

Tags: autohotkey, formatting, list

AHK newbie here,

My problem is simple, I want to make a script that transforms a text with a hotkey.

```
Default text :

AAA : aaa
BBB : bbb
CCC : ccc


Transformed text :

<br><br>
<u>List :</u>
<ul>
<li>AAA : aaa</li>
<li>BBB : bbb</li>
<li>CCC : ccc</li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure there's a way to achieve that with "r n" thingy but I can't find how. Help would be greatly appreciated in this time of need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to map:

- F7 : to be used on the first line of the list
- F8 : to be used on middle-lines
- F9 : to be used on the last line of the list

This is the script :

```
F7:: Send, {Home}<br><br>`r<u>List :</u>`r<ul>`r<li>{End}</li>{Down}
F8:: Send, {Home}<li>{End}</li>{Down}
F9:: Send, {Home}<li>{End}</li>`r</ul>
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)